# Using outer and inner path for material icon SVG

Tags: html, svg

I want to use an SVG image from Material Icon here:
https://material.io/icons/#ic_favorite and here
https://material.io/icons/#ic_favorite_border

My goal is two combine the two SVG paths so that I can show the heart-border at start and when hovering it, showing the filled heart.

I had another idea like this, using a different icon and it worked fine. I use path-outher and path-inner and some simple CSS:

```
<svg height="24px" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <path class="path-outer" d="M17.2385534,1 C15.2451845,1 13.3287082,1.85652572 11.9996333,3.32137937 C10.6710451,1.85652572 8.75505551,1 6.76265989,1 C3.03385303,1 0,4.03190638 0,7.75973991 C0,9.22946018 0.462329224,10.6261811 1.34172807,11.803904 L10.723118,22.8998053 C11.0112221,23.240469 11.4326717,23.4400005 11.8813744,23.4400005 L11.887701,23.4400005 C12.3300771,23.4400005 12.7500667,23.2502022 13.0396308,22.9144052 L22.4258873,12.100768 C23.442525,10.8841121 24.0026733,9.34625914 24.0026733,7.75973991 C24.0026733,4.03190638 20.9683336,1 17.2385534,1 L17.2385534,1 Z"></path>
    <path class="path-inner" d="M21.6851872,11.468107 L12.3047706,22.2768775 C12.2001382,22.3985431 12.0478129,22.4666759 11.887701,22.4666759 L11.887701,22.9533382 L11.884781,22.4666759 C11.7232091,22.4666759 11.5703972,22.3936765 11.4662514,22.2720109 L2.11649452,11.2150425 C1.3684945,10.2125181 0.973324682,9.01532875 0.973324682,7.75973991 C0.973324682,4.56723496 3.57064159,1.97332468 6.76265989,1.97332468 C8.65577639,1.97332468 10.4690803,2.86878339 11.6122501,4.37257002 C11.7042293,4.49423561 11.847308,4.56723496 11.9996333,4.56723496 C12.151472,4.56723496 12.2945507,4.49423561 12.3865299,4.37257002 C13.5306731,2.86878339 15.3444636,1.97332468 17.2385534,1.97332468 C20.4315451,1.97332468 23.0293486,4.56723496 23.0293486,7.75973991 C23.0293486,9.11752784 22.5499862,10.4363828 21.6851872,11.468107 L21.6851872,11.468107 Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

No I try the same approach with Material Icons by using the unfilled heart as the `path-outer` and the filled heart `path-inner`

This looks like this:

```
<svg fill='#31a3f5;' height='24' viewbox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
   <g>
     <path class='path-outer' d='M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5 2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c0 3.78 3.4 6.86 8.55 11.54L12 21.35l1.45-1.32C18.6 15.36 22 12.28 22 8.5 22 5.42 19.58 3 16.5 3zm-4.4 15.55l-.1.1-.1-.1C7.14 14.24 4 11.39 4 8.5 4 6.5 5.5 5 7.5 5c1.54 0 3.04.99 3.57 2.36h1.87C13.46 5.99 14.96 5 16.5 5c2 0 3.5 1.5 3.5 3.5 0 2.89-3.14 5.74-7.9 10.05z'></path>
     <path class='path-inner' d='M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z'></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

However, something is not working here. The un-filled heart does have a different stroke than the original as I would use it without outer and inner paths.
I had the idea to use the `stroke-width` attribute on the g-Tag but that does not apply.

Is it possible to combine the two icons to each other in some way? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `fill` attribute on `<g>` or `<path>`, not on the wrapping `<svg>` element (it has no effect there).

Simple solution using CSS:

```css
/* Using two paths: */

.svg1 .heart-outer {
  fill: #31a3f5;
}

.svg1 .heart-inner {
  fill: transparent;
}

.svg1:hover .heart-inner {
  fill: #31a3f5;
}

/* Using just one path with stroke: */

.svg2 .heart {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #31a3f5;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.svg2:hover .heart {
  fill: #31a3f5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Using two paths:</p>
  <svg class="svg1" height='24' viewbox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
     <path class='heart-outer' d='M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5 2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c0 3.78 3.4 6.86 8.55 11.54L12 21.35l1.45-1.32C18.6 15.36 22 12.28 22 8.5 22 5.42 19.58 3 16.5 3zm-4.4 15.55l-.1.1-.1-.1C7.14 14.24 4 11.39 4 8.5 4 6.5 5.5 5 7.5 5c1.54 0 3.04.99 3.57 2.36h1.87C13.46 5.99 14.96 5 16.5 5c2 0 3.5 1.5 3.5 3.5 0 2.89-3.14 5.74-7.9 10.05z'></path>
     <path class='heart-inner' d='M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z'></path>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Using just one path with stroke:</p>
  <svg class="svg2" height='24' viewbox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
     <path class='heart' d='M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z'></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```